# Why does ':last-child' change the priority of styles?

Tags: html, css

I encountered a scenario which confuses me - usage of `:last-child` affects how parent classes are applied.

What I have is a list of elements, and the goal is to apply some styles to the last element.

However, when I use `:last-child`, the priority of styles changes, and one of the parent classes stops working, only `!important` fixes the problem.

I made a simple demo here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wC2AX/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="hover">
    <div class="focus_on_last_child" style="background-color:red; width:100px;  height:100px">
        <div class="attribution">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*this should be applied on hover always*/
.hover:hover .attribution{
        background-color: black; /*try adding !important*/
        bottom: 0px;

}

/*basic properties*/
.attribution {
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -60px;
    width: 100px;
}

/*depending on a screen size styles are changed*/
.focus_on_last_child:last-child .attribution { /*try removing :last:child*/
    background-color: pink;
    bottom: -30px;
}
```

The example is a little bit stupid, the idea is on hover styles should be changed. But it works only when either `!important` is used or `:last-child` is removed.

Thanks for any suggestions!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue of selector [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity).

Your first rule has two classes and a pseudo-class:

```
.hover:hover .attribution
```

And your last rule also has two classes and a pseudo-class (`:last-child` being that pseudo-class):

```
.focus_on_last_child:last-child .attribution
```

Since your two rules are equally specific, the one that comes later will take precedence. When you remove the `:last-child` pseudo-class, only the two class selectors remain and so the specificity of that rule is reduced, allowing your `:hover` rule to take precedence.

The simplest solution is to move your `:hover` rule underneath your `:last-child` rule, so that rule takes precedence and you won't have to make use of `!important`.

Comment: I just noticed that too. But by the time I had read the question you had answered already...

Comment: Beat me to it, I also don't think @Anelook actually needs the last child selector if the html is as above

Comment: I don't think adding `:hover` underneath the `:last-child` is necessary. You don't need `:last-child` at all, please [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22907075/1248175)

Comment: I don't want to make too many assumptions about the OP's actual code, @Pete and rednaw, that's why I left `:last-child` there.

Answer (score 2):

It's because:

```
.hover:hover .attribution{
```

Is more specific than:

```
.focus_on_last_child .attribution {
```

But if you would add `.hover` to it, it would be more specific, and will work:

```
.hover .focus_on_last_child .attribution {
```